# Ошибка в ExecutorService

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Я передаю поток на выполнение Executorservice в андроиде

```
final ExecutorService downloadService= Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(); 
Thread t =   new Thread() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            DriveContents contents = result.getDriveContents();

                            try {
                                InputStream is = contents.getInputStream();
                                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file1);
                                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                                int bytesRead;
                                //read from is to buffer
                                while((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) !=-1){
                                    os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                                }
                                is.close();
                                //flush OutputStream to write any buffered data to file
                                os.flush();
                                os.close();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
  downloadService.submit(t);
```

но он выдает ошибку

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@298a067f rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@2f9a64c[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RejectedExecutionException` выдается в двух случаях:

1. Очередь пула заполнена
2. Был вызван `shutdown()`

Поэтому, если вы запостили краткую выжимку своего кода, проверьте, что а) вы не сабмитите еще задач, б) не вызывается ли где-то `shutdown()` до вызова `submit()`.

Еще [есть вариант](https://www.farside.org.uk/201309/learning_from_bad_code), что `shutdown()` вызывается GC. `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` возвращает экземпляр `FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService`, который представляет собой обертку над настоящим пулом потоков и при финализации которого вызывается `shutdown()`. Поэтому есть вероятность, что GC добирается до "неиспользуемого" экземпляра раньше, чем вызывается `submit()`.

Comment: да так и есть вызывался shutdown, до завершения.